# Плохое качество изображения с камеры

Tags: android, камера, java

**Всем привет!**

Возникла довольно непростая проблема: при получении изображения с камеры через стандартное приложение Android и при последующем его получении (в методе активности onActivityResult()) его качество просто отвратительно. Метод показан ниже:

```
...

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RESULT);

...

protected void 
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
            Bitmap madePhoto= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        }
    }
```

Камера устройства - 8МП, в стандартном приложении (сразу после создания фото) все отображается идеально, но вот в Интенте приходит какой-то "битый" Bitmap.

Собственно, можно ли каким-то образом исправить такой расклад дел?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo

Comment: Недогуглил как-то :) Скорее оттого, что не имел понятия даже о том, что в интенте приходит лишь превью, а не полномасштабное изображение. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Таким образом вы получаете лиш маленькую превьюшку изображения. Чтобы получить полноразмерную фотку, нужно:

```
Intent pictureActionIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
pictureActionIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri );
startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

То есть нужно в Интент передать Екстра `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, которая бы содержала Uri файла, в который нужно сохранить фотографию. Сделано это из-за того, что передать такой большой объем данных, как фотография, через Интент невозможно. (Микроскопический превью не в счет.)

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Собственно, о том же самом говорится и по ссылке, приведенной @ReinRaus ♦. Кстати говоря, можно это сделать гораздо проще (используя, разумеется, все тот же метод).